# MySQL using a FK vs a Composite index

Tags: mysql, indexing

In a many-to-many table, is it better to use a FK which creates an index for each column, a Composite index since queries will be done on both keys anyway (assuming there are 2 columns), or both FK and Composite at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I would use both.  They serve different purposes.  If by composite index you mean that the combination of columns is unique, then you need that for referential integrity.  You also need foreign keys on both columns for integrity so that each value that exists in the many-to-many table also exists in the table that it maps too.  This simultaneously creates indices used for joins that you will certainly be doing.

Comment: Won't having too many indexes slow down any `UPDATE` or `INSERT` on the tabke if both FK and Composite are used? Or is the composite index not really an issue anymore since both keys are already indexed in the FK?

Comment: @enchance it could slow it down in theory, but it's unlikely to affect you.  The point is that the two different keys are for different things; they don't substitute for one another.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NoSQL instead of RDBMSs if you want to enhance speed.

However, let's consider A and B to be two tables, AID being the key of A, BID being the key of B. You have a many-to-many relationship between A and B, so you create the AB table which has a column for AID and another for BID. If you don't create a primary key, then you might have duplicates, which should be prevented. So you need a primary key for AB. If the primary key is AID, then you are not able to insert two different pairings of the same AID. If AID = 1 has two pairs, BID = 1 and BID = 2, then you will successfully insert AID = 1, BID = 1, but when you try to insert AID = 1, BID = 2, then the system will throw an error, because AID = 1 already exists and is a primary key. In conclusion, you absolutely need a two-dimensional key of (AID, BID) for the AB table.

Let's now turn to the foreign keys. If you don't create a foreign key for AB.AID which references to A.AID, then it is possible to delete a record from the A table and the non-existent id will still exist in AB. So you need to create foreign keys both for AID and BID. This is of higher priority than speed, this is a data integrity protection issue.